# How to add delay to jquery mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of images on one page and I am using the following to trigger an event:

```
$('.img').on('mouseover', function() {
 //do something

});
```

Is there some way to add a delay such that if a user hovers for maybe 1 second, then it does "//do something" or actually triggers the "mouseover" event?

Comment: Check out setTimeout and clearTimeout.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`

```
var delay=1000, setTimeoutConst;
$('.img').on('hover', function() {
  setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
  }, delay);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
});
```

Comment: This does not capture intent. If the user hovers, then mouses away from it, I want it to not actually do what is in the setTimeout.

Comment: I changed code check if it solve your problem

Comment: This inside the setTimeout function seems to change and no longer be the DOM object the function was affecting but instead the window/global object so the function I wrote stops working.

Comment: For Add delay effect of 1 sec on the nav hover.
var menuHoverTimeout;
$(someel).hover(
    function() {
        menuHoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            // do stuff on hover
        }, 1000);
    },
    function(){
        clearTimeout(menuHoverTimeout);
        // do stuff when hover off
    }
);

Comment: I've had to change to  $(".img").hover( in order to work.

Answer (score 33):

You could do that using a `setTimeout` along with a `clearTimeout` if the user leaves too soon:

```
var timer;
var delay = 1000;

$('#element').hover(function() {
    // on mouse in, start a timeout

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // do your stuff here
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    // on mouse out, cancel the timer
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: This makes it very clear why two functions were passed into the hover function, and when each of them are called.

Answer (score 8):

Use a timer and clear it when they mouseout incase they leave within 1000ms

```
var timer;

$('.img').on({
    'mouseover': function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            // do stuff
        }, 1000);
    },
    'mouseout' : function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something like this as well, but with a secondary delay as well. I took one of the answers here and expanded upon it

This example shows a div after X seconds of mouseover and hides it after X seconds of mouseout. But disables if you hover over the shown div.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.foo{
  position:absolute; display:none; padding:30px;
  border:1px solid black; background-color:white;
}
</style>
<h3 class="hello">
  <a href="#">Hello, hover over me
    <span class="foo">foo text</span>
  </a>
</h3>


<script type="text/javascript">
var delay = 1500, setTimeoutConst, 
    delay2 = 500, setTimeoutConst2;
$(".hello").mouseover(function(){
  setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.foo').show();
  },delay);
}).mouseout(function(){
  clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
  setTimeoutConst2 = setTimeout(function(){
    var isHover = $('.hello').is(":hover");
    if(isHover !== true){
      $('.foo').hide();
    }
  },delay2);
});
</script>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/cm2opegm/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery .Delay like this (not tested):

```
$("#test").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).delay(800).fadeIn();
    }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Note that `$(selector).delay()` will ONLY work on animations.