# How to set a delay on .mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have this
`$('#zSlider .description li').mouseover(function(){`

I want the function to execute after 1 second or whatever amount I choose.

This is my first day ever of looking at code of any sorts, i don't know what I'm doing, be specific. I'm just googling and trying to modify stuff on my wordpress page.

Comment: You will not get far if you are not trying yourself and asking for SO to do 100% of the lifting for you.

Comment: or [How to add delay to jquery mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575993/how-to-add-delay-to-jquery-mouseover), etc. etc. Next time you might consider using google first?

Answer (score 0):

The mouseenter event seems better suited for this, and add a timeout :

```
$('#zSlider .description li').on('mouseenter', function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do stuff once the second has passed
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I replaced my line of code with this one but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('selector').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".abc").delay(1000).show(0);
  });
});
```