# Adding a delay in Hover Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I want to add a delay in the hover effect for the code below. I am very weak in jQuery.

```
$(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > a").hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > a").removeClass("active");
    $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > .gallery").removeClass("active");
    $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > div .viewer-border").css({"left":"-9999em"});
    $(this).next().find(".viewer-border").removeAttr("style");

    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575993/how-to-add-delay-to-jquery-mouseover

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay jquery hover event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event)

Answer (score 2):

Set a timer to run your code after your desired delay.  Assuming you want to cancel the action on hover out (here shown with 1000 ms delay):

```
        var id;
        $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > a").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            id = setTimeout(function () {
                $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > a").removeClass("active");
                $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > .gallery").removeClass("active");
                $(".home-furniture .menu > ul > li > div .viewer-border").css({ "left": "-9999em" });
                $(this).next().find(".viewer-border").removeAttr("style");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).next().addClass("active");
            }, 1000);
        },
        function (e) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        });
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried doing this and the entire animation stopped